Ribbon icons size not working properly in word add-in
I'm experiencing an issue with a Word web add-in created using Office.js. I've added several ribbon buttons with icons, but some users can't see certain icons, while others see them without any problems.
Expected Ribbon View:
Expected Ribbon Snapshot
Snapshot with Issue:
Issue Snapshot
I've noticed that when I use the following code in the XML file:
<Icon>
  <bt:Image size="16" resid="SwitchTenant16x16"/>
  <bt:Image size="32" resid="SwitchTenant32x32"/>
  <bt:Image size="80" resid="SwitchTenant80x80"/>
</Icon>

The SwitchTenant80x80 icon displays by default, regardless of screen size. However, when I update the manifest code to:
<Icon>
  <bt:Image size="16" resid="Button16x16"/>
  <bt:Image size="32" resid="Button32x32"/>
  <bt:Image size="80" resid="SwitchTenant80x80"/>
</Icon>

The SwitchTenant80x80 icon loads correctly for some users, but others see only a default icon, as shown in the issue snapshot.
I'm confused about how the icon sizes are being applied and where they are used. Can anyone explain the use cases and how I should test them?
Thanks in advance..
